# Cross database query, looping through databases

Tags: linqpad

Since I have a lot of databases, I'd like to loop through them executing a linq query/update on each of them.

Is it possible to do something like

```
foreach(var r in master.sysdatabases)
{
from b from r.chicken
select b.age;
}
```

I have the premium edition for cross database support.

Answer (score 5):

If all your databases all have an identical "chicken" table, you can do this:

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder (Connection.ConnectionString);

foreach (var db in sys.Databases)
{
   builder.InitialCatalog = db.Name;
   var dc = new TypedDataContext (builder.ToString());
   try
   {
      var query =
         from b in dc.Chickens
         select b.Age;

      query.Dump();
   }
   catch { ... }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  no such thing as sys.Databases, and I tried the view (sysdatabases) in master db, and then I get error on dc.Chickens

Comment: Right-click on the connection, Properties. Check 'Include System Views and SPs'

Comment: The  checkbox has moved slightly in the latest LinqPad version, Now you right-click on the connection, Properties, **Advanced** and  Check 'Include System Views and SPs'

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it like this, but I honestly don't like using string concatenated queries.

```
var r = (from b in Sysdatabases select b.Name).ToList();
foreach(var i in r)
{
try{
    var o = ExecuteQuery<string>("select urls from "+i+".dbo.website_setting");
    Console.WriteLine(o);
}
catch(Exception){}
}
```

the try,execute is for if the table does not exist (master database etc...)